# Como ativar conexão do mysql workbench de forma manual

Tags: sql, mysql

Gostaria de saber como ativar de forma manual a conexão no MySQL WorkBench, sem auxílio de uma IDE de comando como xampp.

Ao que me recordo se fazia essa conexão via gerenciamento de computador, porém não me recordo dos passos seguintes, vou estar anexando uma imagem dos passos que foram feitos por mim.[image: Menu iniciar>gerenciamento de computador>serviços e aplicativos>serviços>SQL Server VSS Writer]

Porém acredito que esses passos não estão corretos, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa instalar o mysql server separado do xampp.

1 - baixe mysql, https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

2 - instale

Após instalar vai aparecer o servico do mysql no seu gerenciador de serviços, assim você consegue iniciar e parar o serviço do mysql.

meu pc:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]